# Google Maps Api Airport Search

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a list of nearby airports, given a certain location.

You can do this through the google places api and using types=airport.

The problem is that Google Places is self-policing so any tom, dick and harry can call themselves an airport.

Is there any way to determine whether an airport is real - through google maps?

I know I could double check against an airports database but then I'd be best just using an external database and only use google maps to plot their locations!!

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) will give you airports eg. a search centred on Central Park New York with a radius of 25 kms.

```
http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=40.776902&lng=-73.968887&fcode=AIRP&radius=25&maxRows=100&username=xxxxx`.
```

You will need to open a (free) Geonames account to make it work.

Such a search would be in your "external database" category but as far as I know, the entries are not self-certified, so are possibly more reliable than Google's from what you say.

To verify Google results against Geonames results would need to develop and code your own comparison algorithm.

Comment: good alternative with better results... distances seem a little out though... thanks

Comment: the json version doesn't seem to understand fcode i.e. it returns all things nearby and limits you to a radius of 1... the documentation appears a bit limited... any idea? json would be better but not the end of the world! thanks

Comment: Hi Graeme, are you sure about that? I just tried the JSON equivalent of the search in my answer and the results look to be fine - 28 of them all with `"fcodeName":"airport"` and `"fcode":"AIRP"`. The lat/lng in each case may well be slightly different from those in the Google results as they will, for the most part, be independently derived.